# static or non-static, that is the question?

Tags: c#, functions, static-methods

For comparisons / evaluations of objects of the same class(and other purposes), is it better to define a static or a non-static (is this called "dynamic" by chance?) function?

Sample code:

```
class student
{
    internal decimal medianOfMarks()
    {
        int count = 0;
        decimal sum = 0;
        foreach(float mark in reportCard)
        {
            counter++;
            sum += mark;
        }
        return sum / count;
    }

    **OR**

    internal static decimal medianOfMark(student delinquent)
    {
        [same logic]
    }
}
```

Let's not consider making the function a property, though parameterless, since I'd like an answer applicable to parameterized functions as well.

What are arguments pro / con each approach?
What deciding factors do exist?
I've already thought into this myself, but I don't want to bias the discussion with my opinion.

Comment: See here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/199735/static-or-non-static

Comment: @blgt that one is more about performance, memory consumption in particular. For me this is more about which one is better style, better comprehensible and good practice.  
I am by far not concerned about running out of memory.

Comment: Do you need access to private members? Yes? Make it a method. No? Make it static.

Comment: @Doval that's the kind of distinction-helpers I'm looking for.

Comment: If you're not concerned about what's under the hood, than @Doval's comment is the alpha and the omega. **static** == no state, **non-static** == state.

Comment: Your function is called *median* but computes the arithmetic mean/average.

Comment: 1) I'd make this a method of `ReportCard`. If you need this on the student, you should forward the call to `ReportCard`. 2) You should use a generic averaging method which takes a sequence of numbers and outputs a number. Such as `Enumerable.LINQ` 3) I wouldn't use `float` on the report card. Either go with `decimal` or with integers representing fixed point numbers.

Comment: I always put static members in a separate section of the source code. This makes it clear that they are completely different from non-static members. Microsoft code analysis automatically warns you if a method could be static, but is not.

Answer (score 1):

Subjectively, I like the non-static instance method, it feels more natural.  YMMV.

Objectively, the static form requires one additional parameter that feels redundant,  i.e.

`myStudent.medianOfMark()`

vs.

`student.medianOfMark(myStudent)`

I'm not a C# wizard so excuse any wrong syntax details.  Also, as others have commented, there are some other issues with naming, using floats, etc...